# GMF Code Generation: Is there any way to customize code generation or reuse already customized GMF code with newer version of eclipse/GMF?

Tags: java, eclipse, emf, eclipse-gmf

I am generating GMF code using by my own xsd, GMF generated */diagram/edit/parts* package and other packages. now i want to do common customization for all classes which extends **ConnectionNodeEditPart** class which exist in */diagram/edit/parts* package. GMF generated a method in the sub classes of **ConnectionNodeEditPart** who's signature is

protected void "addChildVisual(EditPart childEditPart, int index)" 
and method content as below.

```
if (addFixedChild(childEditPart)) {
        return;
}
super.addChildVisual(childEditPart, index);
```

Now i want to customize all addChildVisual methods as follows.

```
if (addFixedChild(childEditPart)) {
        return;
}
super.addChildVisual(childEditPart, -1);
```

This is just changing/replacing **index** to **-1**

There are 1000 class like this, need to modify each time when i am migrating from one eclipse version to next eclipse version. This is a sample/simple change i am discussing. There are other changes in which few methods content was added/changes and few new methods were added to GMF generated code.

When ever we migrate from one eclipse version to next version this tedious code customization part was troubling a lot.

Is there any way to reuse the already customized code with the newer version of eclipse/newer version of GMF. I can group my customizations as say suppose 15 modifications but each change has to do for 1000 number of java classes(same change). **Is there any way to customize code generation or reuse already customized GMF code with newer version of eclipse/GMF??**

Kindly help to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Find the appropriate JET template in the GMF codegen code base and modify the code in the appropriate template. (Template names are rather self-explanatory). Code template files should be OK to digest for those not familiar with JET...

Comment: We are not using any templates like this. are these templates will be generated by eclipse while generating GMF model, edit, editor and diagram code?

Comment: GMF generates the code using the JET templates. The templates are inside the GMF code base. There is a way to override templates, but i don't recall how exactly this needs be done you'd have to read up on this.... However, you can just pull GMF source from the repo, find the appropriate template, modify it and verify that generated code looks as expected.